# Can I use \lstinline for table column?

Tags: tables, listings

I want to apply `\lstinline` to one of the columns. I don't like idea to put it in every cell manually.

I am trying to do

```
\begin{table}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tabular}{| >{\lstinline}l | l |}
        \hline
Имя класса & Назначение\\ \hline
Base & Базовый класс с функциями-утилитами \\ \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
\end{table}
```

But pdflatex just hangs on these lines.

Comment: What is it that you want to do, since there might be other ways of accomplishing what you're after.

Comment: @Werner I want words in one column to be styled as listing. I can write `\lstinline$class_name$` in every column (at least I can use regular expressions to do that automatically) but I hope there are easier ways to do this.

Comment: Is there a reason why this needs to be inside a `tabular` environment?

Comment: @Werner Yes. This should be a placed in a table.

Comment: Did you figure out a way to solve this problem? I would like to do exactly the same thing...

Comment: @Robert I don't remember what was the task, and I didn't touch TeX since 2012, so I don't really understand today what all these syntax thingies mean. But I still have the sources of my work. This very table that I asked about in my question was eventually made like this: http://pastebin.com/p7ngyTqf . It contains text in Russian, much like the question, but it shouldn't hinder the understanding of what's happening there. Look for yourself if it could help you if it's still relevant, unfortunately the only help I can provide is my sources I wrote back then.

Answer (score 3):

You may try the `collcell` package, which allows you to define a column type that applies a macro to the content of each cell of columns of that type. Its applicability might depend on what exactly you want to achieve with `\lstinline` -- refer to the [manual](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/collcell/collcell.pdf) e.g. for the `verb` option.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{collcell}
\usepackage{listings}

\newcommand{\mymacroA}[1]{\textbf{#1}}
\newcommand{\mymacroB}[1]{\lstinline{#1}}

\newcolumntype{E}{>{\collectcell\mymacroA}l<{\endcollectcell}}
\newcolumntype{F}{>{\collectcell\mymacroB}l<{\endcollectcell}}  

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tabular}{| E | F |}
        \hline
        Text & Text \\\hline
        Text & Text \\\hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Works like a charm, however, how about adding column headers?
`\textbf{Column 1} & \textbf{Column 2} \\ ` soon after the `\begin{tabular}{|E|F|}`, for instance, generates an error...